# Not able to keep keep user logged in using checkbox

Tags: php, authentication

i am trying to keep user logged in using checkbox and php but i am getting following error

> Undefined index: stayLoggedIn

my code is as follows

```
<div class="form-group form-check">
  <input type="checkbox"  class="form-check-input" name="stayLoggedIn" value=1> 
  <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1" >keep me  sign in</label>
```

and php code is as follow

```
if ($_POST['stayLoggedIn'] == '1') {
  setcookie("id", $row['id'], time() + 60*60*24*365);
} 
header("Location: loggedinpage.php");
}
```

Please giude where am i going wrong

Comment: Where's your `<form>`? What `method` does it use?

Comment: the logic supplementing your if statement is weird. Why is header function in that place? and why is there a random curly bracket out of place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Undefined index probably means there is no value set, i.e. the box is not checked. Try checking if the variable is set first.

```
if (isset($_POST['stayLoggedIn'])) {
    $stayLoggedIn = $_POST['stayLoggedIn'] ;
}
```

If the $_POST['stayLoggedIn'] isn't set even though the checkbox is checked, you might want to make sure you've sent the form with the right method, i.e.:

```
<form action="pageToHandleForm.php" method="post">
```